# Loop to unzip from one directory to individual directories

Tags: bash, shell, sh, unzip

I am trying to design a loop that implements a lot of single elements I have seen before and the combination is throwing me off.  Basically I have a structure like this:

```
/bin/script.sh
/conf/patches/1.zip
/conf/patches/2.zip
/conf/patches/3.zip
/sharedir
```

I want a loop that will go through however many patches I have in /conf/patches, unzip each patch into a separate directory in /sharedir.  Each directory should be named the name of the file.

What I was trying so far was:

```
for file in '../conf/patches/*.zip'
do
    unzip "${file%%.zip}" -d /sharedir/$file
done
```

As you can see...there is definitely something I am missing in this combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in /conf/patches/*.zip
do
  f="${file##*/}"
  mkdir -p "/sharedir/${f%.zip}"
  unzip -d "/sharedir/${f%.zip}" "${file}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes from glob pattern otherwise it is not expanded:

```
for file in ../conf/patches/*.zip
do
    unzip "${file%%.zip}" -d /sharedir/
done
```

**EDIT:** You can try

```
for f in ../conf/patches/*.zip; do
   echo g="${f%%/*}"
   unzip -d "sharedir/${g%*.zip}" "$f"
done
```

Comment: checkdir:  cannot create extraction directory: /sharedir/../conf/patches/1.zip

That is the error I receive.  I believe this has been my issue.  When it goes through the zip files, it actually creates the "file" name by utilizing the entire path as well as the file name.  Doesn't appear to be dropping the path.

Comment: It does actually run now, but it does not create the directory to unzip into.  It just unzips it all into /sharedir/ I want it to also create the directory for each zip and then unzip into each one.  i.e. /sharedir/1/unzipcontentsfrom1; etc.

Comment: Still does the same thing

Comment: No it doesn't, I have tested this. It created directory structure exactly as in the zip file.

Comment: for file in ../conf/patches/*.zip
    do
        unzip -d "${file%*.zip}" "/oemshare/$file"
    done

Comment: No you cannot do `../` in for otherwise directory name will be messed up.